# Convert array into a single string of url parameters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array of data:

```
[
  { "id": "1001" },
  { "id": "1002" },
  { "id": "1003" }
]
```

I need to convert it into a single string with url parameters like this:

```
https://url.com/data?id=1001&id=1002&id=1003
```

Comment: ```let u = new URLSearchParams(myParams).toString();```
[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var id_list = [
  { "id": "1001" },
  { "id": "1002" },
  { "id": "1003" }
];

var url_param = '';

for(var index in id_list ){
    if( url_param != '' ) url_param += '&';
    url_param += 'id=' + id_list[index].id; 
}

url_param = 'https://url.com/data?' + url_param;
```

I am sure that this will be helpful for you. :)